# Subsetting data through a pairwise condition (coordinates) given through another matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, coordinates, subset

I have the following problem. I want to subset data from data.frame **A** through the coordinates in matrix **B**. The matching must be pairwise between the coordinates of data.frame **A** and matrix **B**, for instance:

```
      lon   lat
315 10.47 52.26
342 10.47 52.37
314 10.36 52.26
341 10.36 52.37
316 10.58 52.26
288 10.47 52.15
343 10.58 52.37
287 10.36 52.15
369 10.47 52.48
```

Those are the coordinates, I want to use to select the rows, which have the same coordinates as in **data.frame A**.

Subset of **data.frame A:**

```
structure(list(V13138 = c(-15.0545539855957, -15.0118608474731, 
-14.8698711395264, -14.7185792922974, -14.5449771881104, -14.3298683166504, 
-14.093412399292, -13.8265686035156, -13.5609474182129, -13.2979116439819, 
-12.9872589111328, -16.1379947662354, -16.0786437988281, -16.0000076293945, 
-15.9013233184814, -15.8254327774048, -15.7928791046143, -15.7776985168457, 
-15.7719392776489, -15.6555442810059, -15.5040102005005, -15.299674987793, 
-15.1203699111938, -14.9610414505005, -14.9183511734009, -14.8809566497803, 
-14.8522186279297, -14.7452983856201, -14.6159820556641, -14.4459781646729, 
-14.2792196273804, -14.1135988235474, -13.919620513916, -13.7100219726562, 
-13.4647169113159, -13.2096605300903, -12.9506988525391, -12.6352672576904, 
-16.0543613433838, -15.9694194793701, -15.8757200241089, -15.7634477615356, 
-15.6610631942749, -15.5705652236938, -15.4900894165039, -15.4035835266113, 
-15.2854766845703, -15.1539916992188, -15.0065212249756, -14.8876695632935, 
-14.7782440185547, -14.7028961181641, -14.6101722717285, -14.512882232666, 
-14.3619556427002, -14.2041110992432, -14.0312938690186, -13.8672027587891, 
-13.7057323455811, -13.5090990066528, -13.2931470870972, -13.0507898330688, 
-12.7776670455933, -12.495795249939, -12.1937398910522, -15.8203887939453, 
-15.7082033157349, -15.5987091064453, -15.4917774200439, -15.390435218811, 
-15.2902202606201, -15.1883487701416, -15.0730466842651, -14.9352264404297, 
-14.8101224899292, -14.6887359619141, -14.5857553482056, -14.479567527771, 
-14.3734302520752, -14.2455368041992, -14.1091232299805, -13.9528331756592, 
-13.7913122177124, -13.6249303817749), V13139 = c(-7.07704830169678, 
-7.36577892303467, -7.60899782180786, -7.85753965377808, -8.1030740737915, 
-8.29149341583252, -8.45194625854492, -8.52234935760498, -8.58086585998535, 
-8.62695598602295, -8.63118934631348, -3.46103024482727, -3.60997128486633, 
-3.75486493110657, -3.90544772148132, -4.07107162475586, -4.2713623046875, 
-4.53771257400513, -4.8378758430481, -5.18377256393433, -5.52214574813843, 
-5.85517549514771, -6.14670562744141, -6.42839002609253, -6.70926380157471, 
-6.97871208190918, -7.23635053634644, -7.43477869033813, -7.61982440948486, 
-7.77778148651123, -7.9507007598877, -8.140061378479, -8.27810287475586, 
-8.39971256256104, -8.4821662902832, -8.54337215423584, -8.59362697601318, 
-8.6127290725708, -3.92732691764832, -4.10400390625, -4.28167676925659, 
-4.4712872505188, -4.68312835693359, -4.91524791717529, -5.20708131790161, 
-5.51510334014893, -5.85246753692627, -6.17613887786865, -6.49274349212646, 
-6.75846433639526, -7.00491952896118, -7.21479940414429, -7.39973735809326, 
-7.57557010650635, -7.69487333297729, -7.81140756607056, -7.91438579559326, 
-8.01808547973633, -8.12346649169922, -8.21732807159424, -8.30572509765625, 
-8.38486099243164, -8.45881938934326, -8.52587699890137, -8.57262134552002, 
-4.34183073043823, -4.54555749893188, -4.76105737686157, -4.99724388122559, 
-5.26278305053711, -5.53893136978149, -5.85093879699707, -6.16052055358887, 
-6.46362257003784, -6.73704147338867, -6.99943161010742, -7.20827674865723, 
-7.38761377334595, -7.53203630447388, -7.64012908935547, -7.74198341369629, 
-7.82141494750977, -7.89632749557495, -7.96634721755981), V13140 = c(2.38613152503967, 
2.37324142456055, 2.38662815093994, 2.38441777229309, 2.35186982154846, 
2.31384658813477, 2.2728853225708, 2.23825240135193, 2.20144987106323, 
2.15977454185486, 2.13386940956116, 2.9677951335907, 2.92966151237488, 
2.8759753704071, 2.8214259147644, 2.76297402381897, 2.70412373542786, 
2.6543300151825, 2.61105895042419, 2.60811114311218, 2.60745763778687, 
2.60840320587158, 2.60350298881531, 2.59271574020386, 2.54244041442871, 
2.47917294502258, 2.40393853187561, 2.35462546348572, 2.31852698326111, 
2.31014728546143, 2.29225921630859, 2.26293158531189, 2.23773765563965, 
2.21094441413879, 2.18223357200623, 2.15001082420349, 2.11311554908752, 
2.08600211143494, 2.89936757087708, 2.89069938659668, 2.87734007835388, 
2.85613536834717, 2.8233802318573, 2.78204131126404, 2.73941993713379, 
2.70192885398865, 2.68653988838196, 2.66766142845154, 2.64770603179932, 
2.62153196334839, 2.5882031917572, 2.53414297103882, 2.46355938911438, 
2.38226866722107, 2.31638383865356, 2.26739454269409, 2.24680852890015, 
2.23866200447083, 2.23337078094482, 2.22489714622498, 2.21137762069702, 
2.19127559661865, 2.16362285614014, 2.13074207305908, 2.08486270904541, 
2.85043382644653, 2.87193655967712, 2.88829565048218, 2.89718008041382, 
2.88119888305664, 2.85316681861877, 2.81990385055542, 2.7852942943573, 
2.75193023681641, 2.72042202949524, 2.6889750957489, 2.650550365448, 
2.60602164268494, 2.55256152153015, 2.48241400718689, 2.40686845779419, 
2.32716631889343, 2.27034878730774, 2.23567771911621), lon = structure(c(10.36, 
10.47, 10.58, 10.69, 10.8, 10.91, 11.02, 11.13, 11.24, 11.35, 
11.46, 8.6, 8.71, 8.82, 8.93, 9.04, 9.15, 9.26, 9.37, 9.48, 9.59, 
9.7, 9.81, 9.92, 10.03, 10.14, 10.25, 10.36, 10.47, 10.58, 10.69, 
10.8, 10.91, 11.02, 11.13, 11.24, 11.35, 11.46, 8.6, 8.71, 8.82, 
8.93, 9.04, 9.15, 9.26, 9.37, 9.48, 9.59, 9.7, 9.81, 9.92, 10.03, 
10.14, 10.25, 10.36, 10.47, 10.58, 10.69, 10.8, 10.91, 11.02, 
11.13, 11.24, 11.35, 11.46, 8.6, 8.71, 8.82, 8.93, 9.04, 9.15, 
9.26, 9.37, 9.48, 9.59, 9.7, 9.81, 9.92, 10.03, 10.14, 10.25, 
10.36, 10.47, 10.58), .Dim = 84L), lat = structure(c(52.15, 52.15, 
52.15, 52.15, 52.15, 52.15, 52.15, 52.15, 52.15, 52.15, 52.15, 
52.26, 52.26, 52.26, 52.26, 52.26, 52.26, 52.26, 52.26, 52.26, 
52.26, 52.26, 52.26, 52.26, 52.26, 52.26, 52.26, 52.26, 52.26, 
52.26, 52.26, 52.26, 52.26, 52.26, 52.26, 52.26, 52.26, 52.26, 
52.37, 52.37, 52.37, 52.37, 52.37, 52.37, 52.37, 52.37, 52.37, 
52.37, 52.37, 52.37, 52.37, 52.37, 52.37, 52.37, 52.37, 52.37, 
52.37, 52.37, 52.37, 52.37, 52.37, 52.37, 52.37, 52.37, 52.37, 
52.48, 52.48, 52.48, 52.48, 52.48, 52.48, 52.48, 52.48, 52.48, 
52.48, 52.48, 52.48, 52.48, 52.48, 52.48, 52.48, 52.48, 52.48, 
52.48), .Dim = 84L)), .Names = c("V13138", "V13139", "V13140", 
"lon", "lat"), row.names = 287:370, class = "data.frame")
```

**Matrix B** with coordinates:

```
 structure(list(lon = structure(c(10.47, 10.47, 10.36, 10.36, 
10.58, 10.47, 10.58, 10.36, 10.47), .Dim = 9L), lat = structure(c(52.26, 
52.37, 52.26, 52.37, 52.26, 52.15, 52.37, 52.15, 52.48), .Dim = 9L)), .Names = c("lon", 
"lat"), out.attrs = structure(list(dim = c(27L, 23L), dimnames = structure(list(
    Var1 = c("Var1= 8.60", "Var1= 8.71", "Var1= 8.82", "Var1= 8.93", 
    "Var1= 9.04", "Var1= 9.15", "Var1= 9.26", "Var1= 9.37", "Var1= 9.48", 
    "Var1= 9.59", "Var1= 9.70", "Var1= 9.81", "Var1= 9.92", "Var1=10.03", 
    "Var1=10.14", "Var1=10.25", "Var1=10.36", "Var1=10.47", "Var1=10.58", 
    "Var1=10.69", "Var1=10.80", "Var1=10.91", "Var1=11.02", "Var1=11.13", 
    "Var1=11.24", "Var1=11.35", "Var1=11.46"), Var2 = c("Var2=51.05", 
    "Var2=51.16", "Var2=51.27", "Var2=51.38", "Var2=51.49", "Var2=51.60", 
    "Var2=51.71", "Var2=51.82", "Var2=51.93", "Var2=52.04", "Var2=52.15", 
    "Var2=52.26", "Var2=52.37", "Var2=52.48", "Var2=52.59", "Var2=52.70", 
    "Var2=52.81", "Var2=52.92", "Var2=53.03", "Var2=53.14", "Var2=53.25", 
    "Var2=53.36", "Var2=53.47")), .Names = c("Var1", "Var2"))), .Names = c("dim", 
"dimnames")), row.names = c(315L, 342L, 314L, 341L, 316L, 288L, 
343L, 287L, 369L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Matrix B** has to have the same column names for the columns with the lon and lat coordinates as **data.frame A**. In the given data, the column names are lon and lat in both objects:

```
head.matrix(data.frame.A)

       V13138    V13139   V13140   lon   lat
287 -15.05455 -7.077048 2.386132 10.36 52.15
288 -15.01186 -7.365779 2.373241 10.47 52.15
289 -14.86987 -7.608998 2.386628 10.58 52.15
290 -14.71858 -7.857540 2.384418 10.69 52.15
291 -14.54498 -8.103074 2.351870 10.80 52.15
292 -14.32987 -8.291493 2.313847 10.91 52.15

matrix.B  

        lon   lat
    315 10.47 52.26
    342 10.47 52.37
    314 10.36 52.26
    341 10.36 52.37
    316 10.58 52.26
    288 10.47 52.15
    343 10.58 52.37
    287 10.36 52.15
    369 10.47 52.48
```

To subset data from **data.frame A** through the coordinates in **matrix B**, just use the following code:

```
subset.A <- merge(data.frame.A, matrix.B)

    lon   lat    V13138    V13139   V13140
1 10.36 52.15 -15.05455 -7.077048 2.386132
2 10.36 52.26 -14.74530 -7.434779 2.354625
3 10.36 52.37 -14.36196 -7.694873 2.316384
4 10.47 52.15 -15.01186 -7.365779 2.373241
5 10.47 52.26 -14.61598 -7.619824 2.318527
6 10.47 52.37 -14.20411 -7.811408 2.267395
7 10.47 52.48 -13.79131 -7.896327 2.270349
8 10.58 52.26 -14.44598 -7.777781 2.310147
9 10.58 52.37 -14.03129 -7.914386 2.246809
```

It's a really simple solution. The columns with the coordinates will be placed in the first 2 columns of the subset.